# Multiplying two $SO(3)$ representations

Tags: tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

In Group Theory by Zee in Chapter IV.2, he discusses the multiplication of two $SO(3)$ representations on p. 207. Suppose you have a symmetric traceless tensor $S^{ij}$ which furnishes a $5$-dimensional irreducible representation and a vector $T^k$ which furnishes a $3$-dimensional irreducible representation, we can then form the product $P^{ijk} = S^{ij} T^k$ containing $5 \cdot 3 = 15$ components. However, $P^{ijk}$ is certainly not a totally symmetric traceless tensor. It is symmetric and traceless in the first two indices, but has no particular symmetry on the interchange of $j$ and $k$, for example.

The process to be done is to first construct the symmetric tensor $U^{ijk} = S^{ij} T^k + S^{jk} T^i + S^{ki} T^j$. Its trace is given by $U^k = \delta^{ij} U^{ijk} = 2 S^{ik} T^i$. Next, we take out the trace by defining $\tilde{U}^{ijk} = U^{ijk} - \frac{1}{5} (\delta^{ij} U^k + \delta^{jk} U^i + \delta^{ki} U^j)$ where there are three terms in the parenthesis due to that we can take the trace in three ways for $\tilde{U}^{ijk}$.

Zee eventually said "there are $(2 \cdot 3 + 1) = 7$ components in $\tilde{U}^{ijk}$". What I did with the counting is to list down the independent components of $U^{ijk}$ such that the indices of the independent components are: $333, 331, 332, 311, 312, 322, 222, 221, 211, 111$ where the combination came up by first considering all indices has a $3$, then only two indices has a $3$, until there is no indices with a $3$. In total, there are ten combos. Now, since there are three ways to take the trace for $U^{ijk}$, it means I need to subtract three constraints so that the independent components of $\tilde{U}^{ijk}$ is $10-3 = 7$.

**Question 1.**

- What does Zee mean when he wrote $(2 \cdot 3 + 1) = 7$? I wanted to know how he did this counting.

Next, he extracted the antisymmetric part of the product $S^{ij} T^k$ by contracting it with the
antisymmetric symbol such that $V^{il} = S^{ij} T^k \epsilon^{jkl}$ so that $V^{il}$ is traceless and has $3 \cdot 3 - 1 = 8$ components. Then he extracted its symmetric and antisymmetric parts such that $W^{il} = V^{il} + V^{li}$ and $X^{il} = V^{il} - V^{li}$.

**Question 2.**

- Can anyone remind me why do we contract with $\epsilon^{jkl}$ when extracting the antisymmetric part of a tensor $P^{ijk} = S^{ij} T^k$ that is not totally symmetric/antisymmetric?
- I'm confused with why take the symmetric/antisymmetric part of $V^{il}$ if contracting $S^{ij} T^k$ with $\epsilon^{jkl}$ should already be antisymmetric (although he just said that $V^{il}$ is traceless, but that's his process after saying that he will extract the antisymmetric part so I'm not sure what is really meant)?

The antisymmetric part can be written explicitly as a vector $\frac{1}{2} U^m = \frac{1}{2} X^{il} \epsilon^{mil} = S^{ij} T^k \epsilon^{jkl} \epsilon^{mil} = S^{im} T^i$ which furnishes a $3$-dimensional irreducible representation. The symmetric part $W^{il} = V^{il} + V^{li}$ is manifestly traceless and has $\frac{1}{2} (3 \cdot 4) -1 = 5$ components. Thus, $5 \otimes 3 = 7 \oplus 5 \oplus 3$.

Comment: Note he antisymmetrized in jk to get his $V^{il}$, but this is of mixed symmetry in il, so he needs to split it into symmetric and antisymmetric pieces.  Can you now streamline your question, which should have deconstructed, in light of these?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Oh yeah, although $V^{il}$ is traceless as a result, it still has mixed symmetry. However, can you explain why we have to contract first with the antisymmetric symbol therefore obtaining $V^{il}$ and just then we take the symmetric and antisymmetric part? I’m guessing this is part of the process of going down from three indexed tensor for which only symmetric traceless is relevant, and then the fewer indexed tensor will also have their corresponding representations as well, and that’s why he used the antisymmetric symbol to “reduce” the indices.

Comment: Right--something like that. I'm not sure if it would help you to think of the indices as a 3dim construct and visualize symmetries and antisymmetries across planes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**.
I don't have that text, but Tony is "cheating" by reminding himself that adding spin 2 to spin 1, your 5⊗3, he gets a spin 3, and a spin 2, and a spin 1, your more tasteful 7⊕5⊕3. His (2⋅3+1)=7 reminds you spin 3 is a septuplet, is all.

Response to **Question 2** and comments on it.
Your basic building block $P^{ijk} = S^{ij} T^k$ is symmetric in (ij) but has no specific symmetry with respect to interchange of the latter two indices jk, so resolves to two pieces, (jk) and [jk],
$$P^{ijk} = (S^{ij} T^k + S^{ik} T^j)/2 +(S^{ij} T^k - S^{ik} T^j)/2 \equiv  R^{i(jk)} +  Q^{i[jk]},
$$ and you may observe any vestige of $ Q$ has disappeared in your U and $\tilde U$.

The antisymmetric pieces  in *Q*  are then converted by ε to the mixed symmetry traceless
$$
V^{il}= W^{(il)} + X^{[il]},
$$
and you got the *W* part.